singular or plural form of noun modifier when noun is plural
Should I say, curriculum assignments are changing? Or should I say, the curricula assignments are changing?

When using a noun like curriculum as a modifier like that, always use a singular noun.

If a house is painted in 3 colors, they do not become the houses paints, just the house paints.

In this case, you're using a noun "as if it were an adjective." (Arguably, it is an adjective in this case, but that's not the point of this question.) In this case it's the antecedent that is the "real noun" and can be plural, but the modifying noun is singular. School buses, traffic lights, soccer balls, ice cream cones.
By the way, there is an adjective form of "curriculum": "curricular." You still might want to use "curriculum assignments" though, as there's a slight shade of meaning. Often adjectives derived from nouns like this mean "having to do with [noun]." E.g. "canine" just means "having to do with, or like, dogs." "Canine teeth" could mean the teeth in dogs' mouths, or the pointy teeth in human mouths. "Dog teeth" is more clearly, well, dog teeth. So "curricular assignments" could be mistaken for "assignments (that is, homework) that are part of the curriculum," while "curriculum assignments" is more clearly "assignments of curricula."

You're confusing word class (POS) and function. The word "curriculum" belongs to the word class noun, and its function is that of modifier.

@BillJ It wasn't part of the question, or maybe even within the purview of this SE, but I'm not sure I believe in "parts of speech." I may be overstating my case, but a less provocative stance would be "I don't know that categorizing words to parts of speech, as in '"dog"' is either a noun or a verb,' is useful."

Of course identifying POS is important. You yourself  used the terms 'noun' and 'adjective' in you answer -- those are POS. Importantly, it is wrong to suggest (as you did) that "curriculum is an adjective; it isn't, it's a noun functioning as modifier of "assignments".

@BillJ A comment section isn't really the place to unpack it, and it's more of an ELU than ELL discussion anyway, but the point is I'd rather focus on function than rigidly categorize a given word. To my mind, if it performs the function of an adjective, it "is" an adjective in this instance. (Or, to put it less inflammatorily, if it performs the function of an adjective, that's what really matters, and I might simply call it "adjectival" and avoid controversy.) In Calvin's quote "Verbing nouns weirds language,"...

...  I would say that he made verbs of the words "verb" and "weird." Of course, that's totally non-standard. But talking this way helps us discuss "quasi-standard" or emerging usages (like whenever it was that "Google" started becoming a verb, or "That's so fetch"), helps rescue poor learners who categorized a word too tightly or incompletely and are flummoxed by a usage outside their memorized parts of speech, and helps them focus on the mechanics rather than the ingredients. Anyway, you'll noticed I hedged my assertion with distancing expressions like "arguably."

(Oops, I misquoted Calvin!)

Nouns can take a range of pre-head (and post-head) modifiers, in addition to adjectives, for example determinatives, nominals and verb phrases. We don't want to call them all adjectives. The term you're missing is modifier, because that is what "curriculum" is in the noun phrase in question.

Using a noun as an adjective is called an attributive noun, and the singular is used.

currilicum development
army blankets
noun clusters
target practice


I chose to use Training Curriculum Assignments. This is the name I gave to the Power BI Report and User Guide that list training curricula, and training courses in these curricula, for a dozen or more job roles.
Now I'm having second thoughts. It just doesn't feel right. The purpose of the Power BI Report is to provide managers with the means to know which training curricula to assign to their teams, e.g., for Job A assign curricula 1, 2 and 3.

If the Report were used by one manager for one job role I'd name it "Job Role Training Curricula." But the Report lists training curricula for dozens of job roles. So, it seemed to make sense to use a name that tied the curricula to their job role assignments.

Maybe it's enough to use a name that simply describes the Report as a list of things without wrapping it in a purpose.
